# Deployment Failed: Info: Sending request: Install and Launch

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I am trying to Launch simple BlackBerry 10 App on the BlackBerry Simulator but the following error occurred.

Deployment Failed: Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
Info: Action: Install and Launch
Info: Debug native: on
Info: File size: 191107
Info: Installing com.example.myApp.testDev_BB10Project8d6810e6...
Info: Processing 191107 bytes
Info: Progress 0%...

Comment: Can you tell if it's trying to deploy an x86 or ARM binary? The simulator will need an x86 binary

Comment: @JohnSibly The app is deploying fine for the first time, but after that I need to restart the Simulator..

Answer (score 0):

Try several times... That works for me. Try different deployment options. Try clicking debug instead of run.

The IDE - Simulator connection is very fragile :-(